# php file upload error warning move_uploaded_file failed to open stream permission denied in

Tags: php, file-upload, file-io, xampp

Here are the two errors

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/uploads53e866b24977d1.48375376.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\file_upload\upload.php on line 28
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php7D69.tmp' to '/uploads53e866b24977d1.48375376.pdf' in C:\xampp\htdocs\file_upload\upload.php on line 28

Here is my HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="">Upload Your Cv</label><input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

Here is my PHP

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $file   = $_FILES['file'];
        // print_r($file);  just checking File properties

        // File Properties
        $file_name  = $file['name'];
        $file_tmp   = $file['tmp_name'];
        $fiel_size  = $file['size'];
        $file_error = $file['error'];

        // Working With File Extension
        $file_ext   = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_fname = explode('.', $file_name);

        $file_fname = strtolower(current($file_fname));
        $file_ext   = strtolower(end($file_ext));
        $allowed    = array('txt','pdf','doc');

        if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed)) {
            if ($file_error === 0) {
                if ($fiel_size <= 5000000) {
                        // $file_name_new     =  $file_fname . uniqid('',true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                        $file_name_new    =  uniqid('',true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                        $file_destination =  '/uploads' . $file_name_new;
                        // echo $file_destination;
                        if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                                echo "Cv uploaded";
                        }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the same code and it works for me. I have made some changes for you.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="">Upload Your Cv</label><input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
</form>
```

After that you don't need to redirect the page; instead you can use *this*, below the `</form>`

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["upload"]))
{
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $file   = $_FILES['file'];
        // print_r($file);  just checking File properties

        // File Properties
        $file_name  = $file['name'];
        $file_tmp   = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_size  = $file['size'];
        $file_error = $file['error'];

        // Working With File Extension
        $file_ext   = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_fname = explode('.', $file_name);

        $file_fname = strtolower(current($file_fname));
        $file_ext   = strtolower(end($file_ext));
        $allowed    = array('txt','pdf','doc','ods');


        if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed)) {
            //print_r($_FILES);


            if ($file_error === 0) {
                if ($file_size <= 5000000) {
                        $file_name_new     =  $file_fname . uniqid('',true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                        $file_name_new    =  uniqid('',true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                        $file_destination =  'upload/' . $file_name_new;
                        // echo $file_destination;
                        if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                                echo "Cv uploaded";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "some error in uploading file".mysql_error();
                        }
//                        
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "size must bne less then 5MB";
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            echo "invalid file";
        }
}
}
```

Note that the upload folder must be in the same directory as where you store the file.

Comment: now the code show no errors but their is no file is showing in uploads folder.

Comment: have u checked if the folder is in the same directory where u have saved the file?

Comment: yes i have upload folder in the directory where i have index.php file and upload.php file

Comment: sorry i forgot to set the name of submit button please set the name "upload" of submit button and it works for sure

Comment: Thnx buddy you saved my day... :)

Answer (score 5):

Probably SELinux did block the file from be written. If this is the case then you should change the context of the file to httpd_sys_rw_content_t   which means it will be turned to a readable and writable directories and files used by Apache.

Assign this to directories where files can be created or modified by your application, or assign it to files directory to allow your application to modify them.

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/path/to/writable/folder -R
```

Comment: You saved my life. All answers about this problem pointing to directory owner and permissions.

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 2):

Directory path should be - `uploads/` if it is present in same directory where your php file is and make sure this directory has `777` permission

```
$file_destination =  'uploads/' . $file_name_new;
if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
    echo "Cv uploaded";
}
```

Comment: how should i change its permission to 777

Comment: In ftp go to 'uploads' folder, right click and select 'File Permissions' change numeric value to 777 and save.

Comment: i am using windows 8.1 their is no File Permissions option on right click

Comment: are you doing this on local or live ?

Comment: i am doing it on local xammp server.

Comment: then pls try to upload your file without changing permissions...it will work.

Comment: i have not change 777 because their is no option of it on right clock how should i change it please help me... :(

Comment: no need to change permissions...just upload your file and submit the form...it should work.

Comment: now the scripts runs but it but the uploaded file is not showing in the folder....

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and have found the solution to this error, it is inside the `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)`

add the following

```
$root = getcwd();
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $root.$file_destination)
```

It turns out you need the full path with some setup, I use XAMPP and had same problem. After playing around for a while I decided to concatenate the root to working directory and it worked out fine.

Comment: At least this `getcwd();`function is working in my case when working locally with XAMPP on Windows 7 ☺

Answer (score 0):

chmod +rwx filename to add permissions. chmod -rwx directoryname to remove permissions. chmod +x filename to allow executable permissions.
...
For example:

```
chmod 777 foldername will give read, write, and execute permissions for everyone.
chmod 700 foldername will give read, write, and execute permissions for the user only.
```